# JsonResult with Base64 encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I use Json(object) to return JsonResult in ASP.Net MVC.

One of the properties in the object is a string that must be Base64 encoded.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string BlockOfText = "Hello World";
}
```

Should be converted to the following Json result

```
{
     "BlockOfText" : "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ="
}
```

How can I tell Json Serializer to encode the property to Base64?

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to encode your string server based.
Before serializing your object just do a :

```
var instance.BlockOfText64Base = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(instance.BlockOfText));
return Json(instance, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Hope it helps.